# Effeciently update 450k rows in mySQL, with a random number

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has **450k rows** in it (and rising). I need to update the `RandSort` column with a random number. I normally use this on my other sites:

```
UPDATE Links SET Timestmp = Timestmp, `RandSort` = if ((@a := floor(8+rand()*113)) BETWEEN 103 AND 109 , 110, @a)
```

This works fine on my normal 20-50k rows. However, it REALLY struggles with this number of rows. I've gone for a less complicated version:

```
UPDATE Links SET Timestmp = Timestmp, `RandSort` = FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *3 )
```

However, this also suffers from being really slow as well.

Is there a better way I can do it, without locking up the table for ages?

*BTW:* The `Timestmp = Timestmp,` part of the query, is just to stop the Timestamp from updating :) (otherwise it changes to the current timestamp)

**UPDATE:** After some suggestions, I have changed the process from doing ALL of the rows at once, to doing smaller 500 batches of 1000. Granted, this doesn't guarantee that everything will be updated (as some may get selected more than once) ... but seeing as this is only a way to randomly sort the rows, this is more than good enough. So the final query was:

```
UPDATE Links SET Timestmp = Timestmp, `RandSort` = FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *3 ) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Use an explain plan, that will tell you why.  It is a bad idea to use UPDATE without "where" statement.  If the updated data are locked by another action, it will just wait until it is released.

Comment: So you mean do `EXPLAIN UPDATE Links SET Timestmp = Timestmp, \`RandSort\` = FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *3 ) ` ?

Comment: @mootmoot - are you suggesting I do this? `UPDATE Links SET Timestmp = Timestmp,
\`RandSort\` = FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *3 ) WHERE 1`. That does seem to have helped (it at least run through this time - even if it did take 5 mins)

Comment: I assume you have an index on `RandSort`, this will slow your updates down. But since random numbers are random and don't have to fulfill any global consistency, you don't have to update them all at once, so you can just update them in batches, e.g. go through your whole table in steps of 50 (or 1000) rows, or just select rows to update at random. Don't do it in a transaction and it will not matter how long it takes, since it will not lock your table for long.

Comment: @Solarflare - thanks. Yeah we have an index on `RandSort`, mostly due to the fact we are using it as part of the sorting process. Thats an interesting idea about doing it in batches. Adding `WHERE 1`  at the end of the queries I originally gave does seem to have helped. I'm not sure why that is the case, but it at least runs now ( in < 5 mins )

Comment: Try running it again without `where`. The effect might happen because  the data is cached after the first run, not because of `where`.

Comment: It is a good idea to export the whole table to your local machine and try out the explain plan. If this is an repetitive task, I will suggest adding another column, update together with the RandSort. e.g.  ```UPDATE Links SET count = new_counter_number , andSort = ... where  count = old_number ```. This allow you to resume to the point where the update stop.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I ended up going for this route, i.e doing 50 updates, but in smaller batches:  `UPDATE glinks_Links SET Timestmp = Timestmp, \`RandSort\` = FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *3 ) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1000 }` - this seems to work well :) (takes about 2-3 seconds per batch)

Comment: Please do a self-answer. Maybe accept it after a few days if nothing stellar arrives from someone else. Versus answering in an update block under your question. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some suggestions from the guys above, I have changed the process from doing ALL of the rows at once, to doing smaller 500 batches of 1000. Granted, this doesn't guarantee that everything will be updated (as some may get selected more than once) ... but seeing as this is only a way to randomly sort the rows, this is more than good enough. So the final query was:

```
UPDATE Links SET Timestmp = Timestmp, `RandSort` = FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *3 ) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1000
```

Thanks everyone for your help. Hopefully this will help someone else in the future as well!

Comment: Thanks for sharing Andrew :p